# Android xamarin visual studio error : 'System.Configuration.dll'

Tags: android, c, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to set up a new xamarin project where i will connect with aws dynamoDB. But now i get this error. I searched everything for it and can't find any good answer for this. I found a 'System.Configuration.dll' file but that was max version 2.0. Any solutions??

Thanks in advance!

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'System.Configuration.dll'
   at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() Grocery
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add a reference from a system.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319{{version}}\System.Configuration.dll

Clean and Rebuild the project and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Start pulling apart your "Portable" project (or your Droid, or similar project).

Somehow you are including a reference that is causing System.Configuration.dll to be dragged in. Comment out anything to do with ConfigurationManager (AppSettings or ConnectionStrings?) and then remove the System.configuration reference.

If you need configuration information, can you get it some other way? E.g. from a web service or manually read from a local "config" file?

Comment: If you need to use a "common" method of configuration, have a look at: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/73623/appsettings-reader-for-xamarin-and-xamarin-forms/p1?new=1

Answer (score 1):

Add new reference to project ,browse and set path for

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319(*version)\System.Configuration.dll

from system.
Rebuild project again.