# Csla.Configuration.ConfigurationManager Exception

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, csla

I'm trying to use CSLA with Xamarin iOS and Andriod. The Xamarin iOS works fine until I add CSLA and do a fetch. It throws an exception on DataPortal.Create(). Having the same issue with Andriod as well. Any help is appreciated.

Error: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Csla.Configuration.ConfigurationManager' threw an exception.

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'Csla.Configuration.ConfigurationManager:_connectionStrings' (1) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. assembly:System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a type: member:(null) signature:

CSLA Version: 4.7.101.0
CSLA Iosui Version: 4.7.200.0

Comment: I've seen this when linking against a windows framework assembly, as opposed to a Xamarin or .net standard lib.  Are you *sure* you've added the right package/library?

Comment: Yes, all the projects in the solution have the correct reference.

Comment: You could try adding a reference to System.Configuration. See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976718/android-xamarin-visual-studio-error-system-configuration-dll?rq=1

Comment: Tried but still no luck :( I have the connection string in my app config but when I try to access it from the Controller, it is blank. ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Name"].ConnectionString

Comment: I ran across this: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/506 which suggests adding this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility/2.0.0

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Another unrelated issue that you are about to encounter, is that you indicate that you are using two different versions of CSLA (4.7.101 and 4.7.200). The data portal requires that the client and server run the _same_ version of CSLA.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are referencing the `CSLA-Core` package instead of the `CSLA-Core-NS` package.

Thanks to a [bug in full .NET](https://github.com/MarimerLLC/csla/issues/822), it is necessary to have a package (`CSLA-Core`) *specifically* for full .NET environments. But for all other environments/runtimes (including Xamarin) you must use `CSLA-Core-NS`.

As further information: .NET Standard doesn't include `System.Configuration`, and so CSLA now provides `Csla.Configuration`. On full .NET this just delegates to `System.Configuration`, and on all other platforms it relies on you to provide a dictionary of app settings values loaded from whatever mechanism you choose to use (read from a file, use .NET Core mechanisms, etc.).

Comment: I changed the reference to CSLA-Core-NS and also made sure the client and the server run the same version. Now I'm getting an error on fetch.

Csla.DataPortalException: DataPortal.Fetch failed (Could not resolve type with token 01000093 (from typeref, class/assembly Csla.Data.ContextManager`1, Csla, Version=4.7.101.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=93be5fdc093e4c30))